# Set bash command output into an azure yml variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm working with Azure DevOps and I need to set the return of bash commands into some variables, for example I have the following:

```
    variables:
      VERSION: 7.2 # works fine
      FILE_VERSION: ${{cat public/VERSION}} # syntax error
```

I tried some some variations from `${{}}` without success and I could not found the right syntax for it, but I think it must be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this in two steps

**STEP 1: Set static value first**

```
  variables:
      VERSION: 7.2
```

**STEP 2: Create step to calculate the value**

Note this will only be available for subsequent steps

```
      - bash: |
          FILE_VERSION="$(cat public/VERSION)"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FILE_VERSION]$FILE_VERSION"
```

Resources:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You should use a [bash step for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts).

Like this:

```yaml
steps:
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FILE_VERSION]$(cat public/VERSION)"
```

Answer (score 1):

We shouldn't use cat command when defining variables. The command should be located in tasks/steps.

According to your description, I assume you're trying to pass the content of public/7.2 to `FILE_VERSION` variable. Here's my test:

1.Azure Devops Git repo:

[image]

2.Define the VERSION variable:

```
variables:
      VERSION: 7.2
```

Run the `cat` command and [set job-scoped variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts):

```
- bash: |
          FILE_VERSION=$(cat public/$(VERSION))
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FILE_VERSION]$FILE_VERSION"
```

The whole yaml:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
      VERSION: 7.2

steps:
- bash: |
          FILE_VERSION=$(cat public/$(VERSION))
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FILE_VERSION]$FILE_VERSION"
          
#Use second bash task to test the variable.
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo $(FILE_VERSION)
```